# Schema Discount code

Tags: schema.org

We are in the process of implementing schema in pages of our coupon website. What is the correct code for "Discount" and "Discountcode".

- Example 1: 30% Off on using coupon code "OFFER1"
- Example 2: 10$ Off on using coupon code "OFFER2"

Example code :

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  "offers": {
    "@type": "AggregateOffer",
    "availabilityStarts": "2017-02-25",
    "availabilityEnds": "2017-03-25",
    "name": "Amazon",
    "discountCurrency": "USD",
    "discount": "10%",    
  }
}
</script>
```

We need to understand if this would work?
If not, what changes should we be making?

Comment: Did you just invent the `discountCurrency` and `discount` properties? If yes, this would of course not work. If no, where did you see them?

Answer (score 1):

[discount](https://schema.org/discount) and [discountCurrency](https://schema.org/discountCurrency) only apply to [Order](https://schema.org/Order), which is for completed Offers. You can't use it on an Offer. There's no defined property specifically designed to represent a discount on an Offer.

However, [Offer](https://schema.org/Offer) seems to be the closest and most appropriate schema for this as you *are* offering a voucher code. Voucher codes can be available or unavailable, with [LimitedAvailability](https://schema.org/LimitedAvailability) and an end date set with [availabilityEnds](https://schema.org/availabilityEnds). For price, you can set [priceSpecification](https://schema.org/priceSpecification).